# Loading an external site into a div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'd like to be able to load an external site into a div - for example googles homepage.

Ive tried:

```
$('#myDiv').load("http://www.google.com");
```

with no such luck.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't just use an iFrame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is dangerous and should be avoided. You've given an example of cross-domain requests and most browsers block you from doing this. You're violating the [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Use an `<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe>` if you really have to.

There's also a supposed solution with jQuery and YQL, but I'll let you sniff that one out.

Comment: I agree.  This can be dangerous

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly, because site you are trying to load is on different domain, and that is forbidden by browsers policy. There are two approaches:

- JSONP - that will work only with page, you can edit
- PHP proxy: load you page through php script located on your site

Comment: There are far more languages than just PHP that you could use to build an HTML proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Your browser is specifically designed to prevent you doing this. Read about the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) for more information.

You have two options for loading content: you can place the external content in an IFRAME, which will let your script cause different pages to be displayed but not interact with their content programmatically; or you can place content hosted on your own servers into a div using jQuery with code such as that in your question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only load content from the same web server using jquery but I might be wrong

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').html('<iframe src="http://google.com" width="100%" height="300">');
```

basic, but would do the trick